# how can i calculate the average age in a java loop?

Tags: java

I was asked to write a program that ask a health worker to  enter the info of the patients he helps each day. But I couldn't calculate the average of the entered age and show the info of which patient is the oldest and who is the youngest. Can anyone help me with this please, I've done the first steps correctly but I don't know how to do the rest.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, i2, i4, a;
    String s1, s2, s3, s4;

    s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Number Of Patients");
    i = Integer.parseInt(s1);
    a = 0;
    while (a < i) {
        s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's ID");
        i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
        s3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Name");

        s4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Age");
        i4 = Integer.parseInt(s4);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ID : " + i2 + "\n Name : " + s3 + "\n Age : " + i4);

        a++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend making another class called `Patient` that has the variables `int id, String name, int age`

Comment: Make a total sum and divide by the number of patients

Comment: And make your variable names more descriptive.

Comment: May be you can create a new class, and have each patient as an Object.
It would be easy for you to then retrieve and compare the values on the fly.

Comment: As @Frakcool said, you shouldn't use variables such as s1, s2, papaya1, papaya2... It makes it hard for both yourself and others who may look at your code in the future. You should be able to look back at an old program (such as this one) and within a few seconds have an overall understanding of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are good. That said, the simplest way would be as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, i2, i4, a;
    String s1, s2, s3, s4;

    s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Number Of Patients");
    i = Integer.parseInt(s1);
    a = 0;
    long totalAges = 0;
    while (a < i) {
        s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's ID");
        i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
        s3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Name");

        s4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter patient's Age");
        i4 = Integer.parseInt(s4);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ID : " + i2 + "\n Name : " + s3 + "\n Age : " + i4);

        totalAges += i4;
        a++;
    }

    double avgAge = ((double) totalAges) / i;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Average Age: " + avgAge);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. for calculating the average of total ages. but at the end how can i  make the program show the information entered of the oldest and youngest patient ? ,, again thank you so much for your help

Comment: You just need to keep track of the current oldest and the current youngest. When the next patient is entered, check to see if they are younger than the current youngest or older than the current oldest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List` interface for storing all the patients age.

Code is like:

```
List<Integer> myPatientAge = new List<Integer>();

myPatientAge.add(i4);


Iterator<Integer> myListIterator = myPatientAge.iterator(); 
while (myListIterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer age = myListIterator.next(); 
    //code for checking the age    
}
```